# Wildfly many couple nodes in custers in same network

Tags: jboss, wildfly, infinispan

I'm trying to configure two separate clusters of wildfly with infinispan as cache server on the same network. I need that the two cluster (say cluster A and cluster B) does not communicate with each other: cluster A is a cluster of preproduction of our application, and cluster B is our cluster for development. Both cluster A and B have their infinispan server. The two clusters have ports and ip different.

I didn't find on the manual or on the net a way to disable/avoid communication between two clusters on the same network; I made a lot of try but with only one success: the infinispan seems to be isolated in its cluster. Now I have hornetq that shares its data between cluster A and B.
Does anyone know how to isolate cluster A from cluster B?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise you to use separate multicast groups for different clusters. You can do it by changing multicast-address attribute of a socket-binding elements for the names jgroups-mping, jgroups-udp, messaging-group, modcluster in a standalone.xml/domain.xml file.

```
<socket-binding-group name="full-ha-sockets" default-interface="public">
    ...
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45700"/> <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45688"/>
    <socket-binding name="messaging-group" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.messaging.group.address:231.7.7.7}" multicast-port="${jboss.messaging.group.port:9876}"/>
    <socket-binding name="modcluster" port="0" multicast-address=”224.0.1.105” multicast-port="23364"/>
    ... 
</socket-binding-group>
```

The first two: jgroups-mping, jgroups-udp are used in the infinispan subsystem and you can change them by passing the jboss.default.multicast.address system property:

```
-Djboss.default.multicast.address=different_group
```

or in server group definition, if you use a domain mode:

```
 <property name="jboss.default.multicast.address" value="different_group"/>
```

The messaging-group group is used in the messaging subsystem (hornetq) and can configured by:

```
-Djboss.messaging.group.address=different_group
```

You should also change the group for modcluster. You can do it either by editing xml file or introducing a new property and passing it analogously as in the previous examples.

More about socket binding you can find at (it’s for Jboss EAP 6.3, but should be the same or similar): https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/sect-Socket_Binding_Groups.html

Here you can find more information about how to choose the right multicast group:
http://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml

I would recommend you use a scope from 239.0.0.0-239.255.255.255 (Organization-Local Scope). For example the second-to-last octet could represent environment (1 for pre production, 2 for development) and the last octet could represent particular multicast group.